# dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed оптимизация приложения android

Tags: android, оптимизация

Каким образом можно оптимизировать приложение android? Я понимаю, что вопрос задан общо, даже слишком, но тем не менее, это мой первый проект и я полагаю, что допустил огромное количесттво ошибок, которые совершают новички. В результате на теефонах более мощных приложение работает, а на более слабых вылезает длиннейший лог состоящий из dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed, я так понимаю из за утечек памяти, хотя я по возможности старался оптимизировать приложение, не оставлять статических ссылок на контекст, и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Такое сообщение возникает при сборке мусора. Возможно Вы создаете множество объектов с малым временем жизни, или все-таки допустили утечку памяти.

В Java часто используются inner классы(они хранят скрытую ссылку на объект родителя) и при неправильной работе с такими классами может возникнуть утечка памяти.

Самый распространенный пример - использование AsyncTask для продолжительных задач. При повороте экрана асинтаск не уничтожается, продолжает работу и при этом хранит ссылку на родительскую активити, и из-за этого она не может быть уничтожена.

А вообще, вот [хорошая заметка](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/activitys-threads-memory-leaks.html) об утечках памяти в android